# Watermark image size scaling in php

Tags: php

Here is my code..

```
$abc1 =$obj->image_1; //comming from database
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng("../image/product/stamp.png");
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("../image/product/$abc1");
$save_watermark_photo_address ="../image/product/$abc1";

$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

imagejpeg($im, $save_watermark_photo_address, 80); 
imagedestroy($im);
```

This code is working fine but the size of watermark image is large . I Want to make it small size and put it to left side down corner on `$abc1` image .

Comment: just use smaller numbers in `imagecopy()`. `$sx /= 2; $sy /= 2;` would make it half the size.

Comment: So tweak those parameters until you get the desired results

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with your own adaption.

```
<?php
// Load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('stamp.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('photo.jpeg');

// Set the margins for the stamp and get the height/width of the stamp image
$marge_right = 10;
$marge_bottom = 10;
$sx = imagesx($stamp);
$sy = imagesy($stamp);

// Copy the stamp image onto our photo using the margin offsets and the photo 
// width to calculate positioning of the stamp. 
imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

// Output and free memory
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```